# PostgreSQL 11: How to `ALTER SCHEMA **IF EXISTS** RENAME TOO…`

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

**Context**
I am writing a (Python) script to automate the (re)creation from scratch of the schema `foo` on my PostgreSQL 11.2 database.

I want my script to handle both following cases:

- a schema named `foo` already exists in my database
- there is no schema named `foo` in my database.

**Problem**
I'm not very brave, and would prefer to keep a copy of this already existing schema, instead of simply `DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS foo;`.

However, the command `ALTER SCHEMA IF EXISTS foo RENAME TO foo_backup_2019-07-29T1317210;` does not exists:

```
# ALTER SCHEMA IF EXISTS foo RENAME TO foo_backup_2019-07-29T1317210;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXISTS"
LINE 1: ALTER SCHEMA IF EXISTS foo RENAME TO foo_backup_2019-07-29T1...
```

**Question**

> How to rename `foo` at the condition such a schema already exists in my database?

Comment: There is no `alter schema if exists` modification of `alter schema` statement in postgre

Comment: @Y.K. you are right, and this is why I'm asking this question: how to emulate `alter schema if exists`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016419/postgresql-check-if-schema-exists There are already some good answers I think...