# Skip SQL Schema if its not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote an SQL query that combines extracting data from multiple schemas but when the project gets archived schemas get deleted and my query failed. I was wondering if there a way to amend the query to skip the schema when its not exists.

Here is an example of my query:

```sql
SELECT * from dd12

UNION ALL

SELECT * from xx15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check schema is exists or not with this query:

```sql
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'name';
```

replace `'name'` with your schema name. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7021871/7865759) answer for more detail

and for condition you can use `CASE`:

> The SQL CASE expression is a generic conditional expression, similar to if/else statements in other programming languages.

postgresql condition [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-conditional.html)